# ParametersIncrementer not working while triggering spring batch job

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to trigger a spring batch job and expect run.id as a job param to be passed after adding RunIdIncrementer while defining the job bean . But from the logs it looks like the param is not getting passed.

Job Bean

```
  public Job firstPartyStatsIngestionJob() {

    return jobBuilderFactory.get(TradingCenterJobName.firstPartyStatsIngestionJob.name())
        .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
        .start(getFirstPartyIngestionStep())
        .build();
  }
```

Here I expect a job param **run.id** to be passed when the job is triggered but in the logs, all I see is **launched with the following parameters: [{}]**

```
[INFO ] 2022-12-16 09:04:07 [main      ] [/] [] JobLauncherApplicationRunner:154 - Running default command line with: []
[INFO ] 2022-12-16 09:04:07 [main      ] [/] [] SimpleJobLauncher:146 - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=firstPartyStatsIngestionJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
```

key dependencies and versions

spring-boot: 2.5.12
spring-batch-core : 4.3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try launching the job using the `JobOperator.startNextInstance` method...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/JobOperator.html#startNextInstance(java.lang.String)

If running from the command line, you can specify the -next argument...

https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html

Comment: we have a use case to trigger the batch job by passing --spring.batch.job.names. And isn't just adding the incrementer while defining the job be sufficient?

Comment: You need to use a method that will invoke the incrementer and it's not always obvious which methods will or won't invoke the incrementer automatically.  Another way is to use the `JobParametersBuilder.getNextJobParameters` method...
https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobParametersBuilder.html#getNextJobParameters(org.springframework.batch.core.Job)

Comment: If using the CommandLineJobRunner you can specify -next.  Added that to the answer